# Using callable(x) vs. hasattr(x, "__call__")

Tags: python, python-3.x, callable

I'm writing Python that targets versions 3.2 and higher. It looks like using the built-in function callable is the most straightforward and efficient way to do this. I've seen recommendations for `hasattr(x, "__call__")`, `collections.Callable(x)`, and just using `try/except` around an attempted call.

I've tested items that are callable (a class and a function), using `timeit` with 100,000 iterations; in both cases using callable takes only about 75% of the time of checking for the attribute. When the item is not callable (an integer and a string) using callable stays at the same cost as a class or function while checking for the attribute is about 2.3 times more expensive than for a class or function. I didn't expect that difference, but it also favors the clear and concise `callable(x)` approach.

But I'm relatively new to Python and no expert, so are there reasons I'm not aware of that I should use the hasattr approach or another approach?

FWIW, the results of the various timeits follow. The first character is just t for timeit, the second indicates what the type of the object being tested (c = class, f = function, i = integer, s = string), and the rest indicates the method (attr - check attribute, call - use callable, try - use try/except).

```
tcattr 0.03665385400199739
tccall 0.026238360142997408
tctry 0.09736267629614304
tfattr 0.03624538065832894
tfcall 0.026362861895904643
tftry 0.032501874250556284
tiattr 0.08297350149314298
ticall 0.025826044152381655
titry 0.10657657453430147
tsattr 0.0840187013927789
tscall 0.02585409547373274
tstry 0.10742772077628615
```

Comment: sidenote: callable was [removed in python3.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3100/#built-in-namespace) and - after noticing that this [was a bad choice](http://bugs.python.org/issue10518) - [brought back in 3.2](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html?highlight=callable#callable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hasattr()` will return more false positives than `callable`:

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         return name
...
>>> i = X()
>>> from collections import Callable
>>> isinstance(i, Callable)
False
>>> callable(i)
False
>>> hasattr(i, '__call__')
True
>>> i()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'X' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure which `callable` you were testing, but both look nicer than `hasattr` and handle more cases, so I would use them in place of `hasattr()`.

Comment: [`callable`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) can also return [false positives](http://ideone.com/PexRWg).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - True, but only a crazy person would define a class with a non-callable `__call__`. That'd just be a bug in real code.

Comment: Thank you both for the perspective. For completeness I was using the built-in callable, not the collections.Callable.

Answer (score 5):

`callable` is not only the fastest, but the [Zen](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) provides four more important reasons to use it instead of the other two contraptions:

> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>   Explicit is better than implicit.
>   Simple is better than complex.
>   Readability counts.

Answer (score 5):

Great question! I'd say you should use `callable`. Several points apart from the speed issue:

1. It's explicit, simple, clear, short, and neat.
2. It's a Python built-in, so anyone who doesn't already know what it does can find out easily.
3. `try... except TypeError` has a problem: `TypeError` can sometimes be raised by other things. For example, if you successfully call a function which raises `TypeError` in its body, the `except` will erroneously catch that and assume that the object was not callable.
4. Some common customisations, like `__getattr__`, can cause `hasattr` to make mistakes.
5. `collections.abc.Callable` seems like rather heavy machinery for something so simple. After all, `callable` does the same job.

Footnote: the `try` block is a [very common pattern](http://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) in Python for this sort of thing, so you may see a lot of it in other people's code. However, as I've outlined above, this is one case where it's not quite suitable.