# How can I distinguish data member and function member with dir() in python?

Tags: python, function, methods, attributes, datamember

```
class Vehicle:
    speed = 0
    def __init__(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed

    def drive(self, distance):
        print 'need %f hour(s)' % (distance / self.speed)

print dir(Vehicle)
```

The Pycharm shows:
`['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'drive', 'speed']`

But given that 'speed' is a member data, 'drive' is a member function, why are there no brackets after 'drive'?

How can I distinguish data member and function member with dir() in python?

If dir() only lists attribute names, then how can I list all the data members and methods in a class?Otherwise, when I want to call an attribute, how do I know whether it needs parentheses after the attribute name or not?

Is there a function simply show all the data member and method in a class directly

Comment: The semantics of `dir()` are very well defined.  It is mostly meant to be used for convenience in interactive use.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As an aside: I would remove the `speed = 0` from outside the `__init__`, since I assume you want each vehicle to have its own speed. Check out [the difference between a class member and an instance member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/207000/198633)

Comment: `dir()` lists attribute names, i.e. names that can be looked up on the object using `getattr(obj, name)`.  An attribute name never contains parentheses, which is why they are not included.  There also isn't a clear distinction between data members and methods, since functions are first-class values in Python.

Comment: Argh, this was supposed to be "The semantics of dir() are _not_ very well defined."

Comment: @SvenMarnach If dir() only lists attribute names, then how can I list all the data members and methods in a class?Otherwise, when I want to call an attribute, how do I know whether it needs parentheses after the attribute name or not?

Comment: @user8394497 If you want to call an object, you always need parentheses, since that's the function call operator in Python.  In general, you should look at the documentation of the library you are using or at the source code to understand how to use interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

To check if an attribute is a function, call type(attribute) will get you its type back.

```
import types
functions = (types.BuiltinFunctionType, types.BuiltinMethodType, types.FunctionType)
s = 'test'

for i in dir(s):
    attr_type = getattr(s, i)
    if isinstance(attr_type, functions):
        print i, attr_type
```

This will print you all the attributes which are functions.

EDIT: changed list compherension solution to `isinstance` builtin as suggested by **Sven Marnach** in the comments.

Comment: You should use the `callable()` built-in to check whether an object is callable.  Your test breaks in some cases.

Comment: callable() will return true if an object implements `__call__`. Some classes implements this to make the objects callable, and they are not necessarily functions. From the doc `class instances are callable if they have a __call__() method.` Hence, callable here doesn't fit. And if you can please give an example when it breaks, so I can learn.

Comment: This very much  depends on what the OP really wants.  My reply in the comments was that there simply isn't a fundamental difference between data members and methods, so it all depends on what you are trying to achieve.
An example where `hasattr(obj, '__call__')` does not work as expected is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16388171/279627

Comment: And more generally, if there is an official way of doing something, you should stick to it.  For testing whether something is callable, use the built-in specifically made for this purpose.  When checking whether and object has one of several types, use `isinstance(attr, tuple_of_type)`.

Comment: I agree, and that's the reason I edited my answer and provided a different solution. `hasattr(obj, '__call__')` doesn't fit here

Comment: If dir() only lists attribute names, then how can I list all the data members and methods in a class?Otherwise, when I want to call an attribute, how do I know whether it needs parentheses after the attribute name or not?

Comment: @user8394497 `dir()` lists all attributes of an object, including variables and methods. If you want to know if an attribute is a method (hence the need for parenthesis) you can simply check `callable(obj.method)`. In my example, calling `callable(s.split)` returns True since split() is a method of str objects.

Comment: @Vinny thanks.If an attribute is a data member,will callable return false?Is there a function simply show all the data member and method in a class directly?

Comment: @user8394497 if it's not callable, then it returns false. I'm not familiar with a such function

Answer (score 1):

> `speed` is a member data,`drive` is a member function, why there is no brackets after `drive`?

From `help(dir)`:

> ...return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the attributes of the given object, and of attributes reachable from it...

That being said, `dir` doesn't bear the responsibility of recognizing the differences between objects, instead it shows you the attributes that are accessible in a given namespace. However, Python is dynamic and you could very easily manipulate the results returned by `dir`, for example you could do use this under 3.X:

```
from types import FunctionType
allMethods = [] 

# get rid of builtin names: __str__, __repr__,... 
user_defined_objs = [name for name in dir(Vehicle) if not name.startswith("__")]  

for name in user_defined_objs:
    obj = getattr(Vehicle, name)
    if isinstance(obj, FunctionType): # function? 
        allMethods.append(name)
```

There's nothing special in this code.`FunctionType` is the class from which function objects are created. In 3.X, `Vehicle.drive` is a function, however, `Vehicle().drive` is a bound method, in 2.X this is slightly different. We just filter those objects according to their types. In 3.X, `Vehicle.drive` when referenced from the class *not* from an instance like: `Vehicle().drive` it's an instance of `FunctionType`.

Comment: Did you mean `Vehicle.drive` and `Vehicle().drive` instead of `Vehicle.speed` and `Vehicle().speed`?

Comment: @nanotek My bad, yes.

Comment: If dir() only lists attribute names, then how can I list all the data members and methods in a class?Otherwise, when I want to call an attribute, how do I know whether it needs parentheses after the attribute name or not?

Comment: @user8394497 Have you looked at the code I provided? `dir` lists all attributes that are accessible within a namespace (inherited attrs) _plus_ attrs within that namespace, *not just the attributes within that namespace. You could also use `callable` builtin function to check if an object is callable: `obj()`. Let me know if you're still confused.